# How do I prevent my form action (html) from going through with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

TL;DR I just want to know how to (conditionally) stop form actions from executing with javascript.

I made an html page that redirects you to /game.html when you click the submit button:

```
<form class = "initial-form" action = "/game.html">
    <!--a bunch of input elements-->
    <button type = "submit" value = submit id = "go-button">Go</button>
</form>
```

However, I also attached a script to the html that checks the input for errors. Ideally, it stops the form action from going through if the input is invalid, but I'm not sure how to do this. Here's the relevant script code:

```
const $send = document.getElementById('go-button')

$send.onclick = ()=>{

const player = {
    roomName: "",
    username: ""
  }

  //populate player
  const joinOption = document.querySelector('input[name="join-option"]:checked').value
  player.roomName = $roomname.value
  player.username = $username.value

  socket.emit('validate-player', player, joinOption)
}

socket.on('validate-player-client', (res)=>{
  console.log(res)
  if(res.error){
    return alert('Error: ', res.error)
  }
  else if (res.approved){
    return alert('approved')
  }
})
```

I know this is kind of hard to follow, but 'validate-player' is a request to the back-end (in node) to check if the player properties are all valid. The back end will then emit 'validate-player-client', sending an object with either an 'approved' property or 'error' property. I want to stop the form action from navigating to /game.html when an object with an error property is returned. How would I do this?

Thanks guys!

Comment: submit events preventDefault method should help

Comment: I want to prevent the form action from going through on socket.on('validate-player-client') though. Doesn't this mean that I wouldn't have access to the event argument?

Comment: if what you're waiting for is asynchronous, then you will have to re-think your code to **always** prevent the form submit, and "programatically" perform a submit upon validation - of course, the same onsubmit code would be called, so you'll need to be clever

Comment: actually, if you make the button NOT a submit button, then it's very easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your button NOT a submit button, and move it outside the form

```
<form class="initial-form" id="theForm" action="/game.html">
    <!--a bunch of input elements-->
</form>
<button type="button" id="go-button">Go</button>
```

Now this code will submit the form `.on('validate-player-client'`

```
const $send = document.getElementById('go-button');
// make this button NOT
const form = document.getElementById('theForm');

$send.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const player = {
        roomName: "",
        username: ""
    }
    //populate player
    const joinOption = document.querySelector('input[name="join-option"]:checked').value
    player.roomName = $roomname.value
    player.username = $username.value
    socket.emit('validate-player', player, joinOption)
}

socket.on('validate-player-client', (res)=>{
    console.log(res)

    if(res.error){
        alert('Error: ', res.error);
    }
    else if (res.approved){
        form.submit();
    }
    else {
        // do something else here I guess
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onSubmit()` and return `true` or `false` based on your condition.

```js
function onSubmit() {
  if (document.form.name.value == '') {
    console.log('invalid');
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log('valid');
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form" onSubmit="return onSubmit()">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <button type="submit">Check</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there a way to emulate action='/game.html' in javascript ? Unfortunately the function that stops the form action needs to wait for an event to be emitted from the backend (i.e. button click sends request to server; function that decides whether or not to stop or allow the form action waits on response from server). I don't think I can stop it your way.